# How much preprocessing Vowpal Wabbit input needs?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-processing, vowpalwabbit

I know that vw can handle very raw data(e.g. raw text) but for instance should one consider scaling numerical features before feeding the data to vw?
Consider the following line:

`1 |n age: 80.0 height: 180.0 |c male london |d the:1 cat:2 went:3 out:4`

Assuming that typical age ranges from 1 to 100 and height(in centimeters) may range from 140 to 220, is it better to transform/scale the `age` and `height` so they share a common range? I think many algorithms may need this kinda of preprocessing on their input data, for example Linear Regression.

Answer (score 2):

`vw` SGD is highly enhanced vs the vanilla naive SGD so pre-scaling isn't needed.

If you have very few instances (small data-set), pre-scaling may help somewhat.

`vw` does automatic normalization for scale by remembering the range of each feature as it goes, so pre-scaling is rarely needed to achieve good results.

Normalization for scale, rarity and importance is applied by default. The relevant `vw` options are:

```
--normalized
--adaptive
--invariant
```

If any of them appears on the command line, the others are not applied.  By default all three are applied.

*See also:* [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770631/1296044)

*The paper explaining the enhanced SGD algorithm in `vw` is:*

[Online Importance Weight Aware Updates - Nikos Karampatziakis & John Langford](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1576)